# Why am I receiving a name error for a name not defined that I haven't included in my code?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter, scheduler

Using this code in my website update tool, I receive a NameError: name 'new_link1' is not defined. However I use the name new_link in my code, not new_link1. I am using Jupyter notebooks with some other notebooks running similar code if that might be having an effect. My code is below.

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import schedule
    import time

    # Electricity Northwest Code   
    def get_link():
       url = 'https://www.enwl.co.uk/about-us/financial-investor-relations/information-for-investors/'
       reqs = requests.get(url)
       soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')

    changing_link = soup.find('a', {'class': 'c-downloads__link js-downloads__link'}).get('href')
    return changing_link

   def handle_changes_to_link(value):
       new_link = get_link()
       if not new_link == value:
            print('New Update from ENWL, remember to copy and paste new link: ', new_link)

   #When an update has occured copy and paste new link into value = 'https://new link here'  below

   schedule.every(30).seconds.do(handle_changes_to_link, value = 'https://www.enwl.co.uk/globalassets/investor-relations/documents/non-password-protected/enw-finance-plc-prospectus-july-2020')
   while True:
       schedule.run_pending()
       time.sleep(10)
```

And the error I see is:

```
    NameError: name 'new_link1' is not defined
```

Edit: full stack trace below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [9], in <cell line: 25>()
     23 schedule.every(30).seconds.do(handle_changes_to_link, value = 'https://www.enwl.co.uk/globalassets/investor-relations/documents/non-password-protected/enw-finance-plc-prospectus-july-2020')
     24 while True:
---> 25     schedule.run_pending()
     26     time.sleep(10)

File /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py:780, in run_pending()
    776 def run_pending() -> None:
    777     """Calls :meth:`run_pending <Scheduler.run_pending>` on the
    778     :data:`default scheduler instance <default_scheduler>`.
    779     """
--> 780     default_scheduler.run_pending()

File /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py:100, in Scheduler.run_pending(self)
     98 runnable_jobs = (job for job in self.jobs if job.should_run)
     99 for job in sorted(runnable_jobs):
--> 100     self._run_job(job)

File /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py:172, in Scheduler._run_job(self, job)
    171 def _run_job(self, job: "Job") -> None:
--> 172     ret = job.run()
    173     if isinstance(ret, CancelJob) or ret is CancelJob:
    174         self.cancel_job(job)

File /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py:661, in Job.run(self)
    658     return CancelJob
    660 logger.debug("Running job %s", self)
--> 661 ret = self.job_func()
    662 self.last_run = datetime.datetime.now()
    663 self._schedule_next_run()

Input In [2], in handle_changes_to_link(value)
     16 new_link = get_link()
     17 if not new_link == value:
---> 18     print('New Update from ENWL, remember to copy and paste new link: ', new_link1)

NameError: name 'new_link1' is not defined
```

Comment: Well you can see in the stacktrace you are trying to print `new_link1`.

Comment: @Guy apologies if this is naive (I'm new to python) but why does it think I'm trying to print new_link1 if this isn't included in my code?

Comment: If you've some scheduled code running in background, then kill it and restart kernel.

Comment: This is an IDE issue, not Python. I'm not familiar with Jupyter notebook, but maybe you need to save changes or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The [comment by @Azhar-Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73191759/why-am-i-receiving-a-name-error-for-a-name-not-defined-that-i-havent-included-i/73208723#comment129265289_73191759) solved the problem:

> If you've some scheduled code running in background, then kill it and restart kernel.